# How do Hangfire's short polling intervals harm SQL Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server, polling, hangfire

In [Hangfire's documentation](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html#configuring-the-polling-interval), there's a mention of polling interval (when using SQL Server as the storage):

> You can adjust the polling interval, but, as always, lower intervals can harm your SQL Server, and higher interval produce too much latency, so be careful.

What I'm wondering is **how exactly do short polling intervals harm SQL Server**? What will I see if Hangfire starts polling every 5 seconds instead of the default 15 seconds? Can it significantly affect the performance of non-Hangfire queries?

Answer (score 0):

Also from the [docs](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/configuration/using-sql-server.html#configuring-the-polling-interval) you linked:

> One of the main disadvantage of raw SQL Server job storage implementation – **it uses the polling technique to fetch new jobs**

Hangfire doesn't keep a list of jobs it's needs to run in memory, instead it asks the database every X seconds for new jobs.

A shorter polling interval means Hangfire needs to query the database more often.

Comment: Is that really all there's to it? Let's say I set it up on the shortest interval possible, which is 1 second. Why does it harm the SQL Server to run a trivial identical query once every second? Usually, it can handle like hundreds of queries per second that are much more complicated. So why does the author recommend to be so cautious there?

Comment: What makes you think the query is trivial? It probably is, I've not checked. The author has to be cautious, any library creator should be. On your server a few extra queries may be fine, but let's say you have a server farm with 20 web servers all querying at the same time. Or how about your database is running on a low power box?

Comment: I wonder if maybe each Hangfire worker is polling separately. If there are like 20 workers and each of them poll the same table (probably with some locks), I imagine it could cause issues. Do you happen to know about how Hangfire workers work?

Comment: Oh sorry, I got confused between workers and servers - I have no idea how workers work.